# How to Stop RSpec Warning Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have just started learning to use RSpec on my rails application.
It all seems to work ok, but when I run `rspec spec` I get pages and pages of what I think are lint messages.

I don't mind the ones that refer to my code, but lots of them refer to Gems that I am using.
I can't really fix those.

How can I configure RSpec to apply lint only to my code and not external Gems?

Here is a small sample.  I get over 2000 lines of this stuff.

```
/Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/lib/sorcery/model.rb:265: warning: method redefined; discarding old username_attribute_names=
/Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/lib/sorcery.rb
    from /Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
    from /Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/jcreasey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcreasey
```

This is my .rspec file

```
-color
--warnings
--require spec_helper
```

Comment: Do you have `/.rspec` file?

Comment: Looks like --warnings is what is causing it.  Post as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have `/.rspec` file remove `--warning` option from it.

Comment: Same answer really, but I found that my `./spec/spec_helper.rb` file contained the line: `config.warnings = true`