# Pry gives a bunch of warnings

Tags: rspec, pry, yard

Requiring `pry` in my RSpec `spec_helper.rb` and running my specs gives me a bunch of warnings. How do I get rid of these?

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/commands/bang.rb:3: warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/commands/cat/file_formatter.rb:54: warning: assigned but unused variable - ext
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/commands/ls/formatter.rb:43: warning: method redefined; discarding old grep
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:22: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:42: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:172: warning: method redefined; discarding old memory_size
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/config/convenience.rb:22: warning: previous definition of memory_size was here
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:176: warning: method redefined; discarding old memory_size=
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/config/convenience.rb:23: warning: previous definition of memory_size= was here
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:602: warning: method redefined; discarding old pager
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/config/convenience.rb:22: warning: previous definition of pager was here
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:609: warning: method redefined; discarding old output
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/config/convenience.rb:22: warning: previous definition of output was here
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pager.rb:41: warning: private attribute?
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/docstring.rb:175: warning: assigned but unused variable - open_parens
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/docstring.rb:176: warning: assigned but unused variable - close_parens
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/docstring_parser.rb:118: warning: character class has duplicated range: /\A[\r\n\s]+|[\r\n\s]+\Z/
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/docstring_parser.rb:138: warning: assigned but unused variable - tag_klass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/tags/library.rb:236: warning: assigned but unused variable - arity
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/docstring_parser.rb:118: warning: character class has duplicated range: /\A[\r\n\s]+|[\r\n\s]+\Z/
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/logging.rb:179: warning: instance variable @progress_msg not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.4/lib/yard/logging.rb:179: warning: instance variable @progress_msg not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/commands/whereami.rb:140: warning: instance variable @method_code not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/code.rb:267: warning: instance variable @with_indentation not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/code.rb:267: warning: instance variable @with_indentation not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/code.rb:267: warning: instance variable @with_indentation not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/code.rb:267: warning: instance variable @with_indentation not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/code.rb:267: warning: instance variable @with_indentation not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pager.rb:136: warning: instance variable @system_pager not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pager.rb:185: warning: instance variable @pager not initialized
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pager.rb:185: warning: instance variable @pager not initialized
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Stop RSpec Warning Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103610/how-to-stop-rspec-warning-messages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `--warning` option from `.rspec` file.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `.rspec` file in your project or the `.rspec` file has no `--warning` option, you'll want to open `spec/spec_helper.rb` and set `config.warnings = false`.

Try to avoid staging the `.rspec` file and instead put all your RSpec configurations in your `spec_helper.rb`. The `.rspec` should be used by developers to override any basic configurations so they can run RSpec in their preferred way (e.g. with warnings, with colour, with random order, etc. if the project settings haven't configured it to their liking already).